# Problems with 2nd Gmail address affecting Blogger and Google+ profile

Tags: gmail, google-plus, google-account, blogger

I have a small business and I have a blog using Blogger (http://straightforwardconsultancy.blogspot.co.uk) which I set up using a Gmail address and later connected to a Google+ profile. All was fine from Jun-13 til around Mar-14 when 
I created a new Gmail account (in error) so I could have visibility of my diary on all devices, laptop, iPhone, iPad, etc. I completely forgot I had the original Gmail account.

Now I can't sign into Blogger with the first Gmail address, only the new one and there are no blogs associated with the original email address when I sign into Google/Google+. I now also appear to have 2 Google sign ins (one for each email address) and two Google+ profiles (each linked to a Gmail account).

Under Permissions in Blogger, the new Gmail address is sitting there as the only author and the other has disappeared. All the blogs are there though but they dont show in Google+. The same address is also showing in settings. How did it do that?

How do I reassociate the blog with my original Google email address/Google/Google+ profile and make the orginal Gmail account the primary one and I can go back to the original profile and start posting as I did before?

It's pretty confusing but maybe you have seen this before.

I would be willing to delete my new Gmail account and if need be and have my business email address as a back up but would prefer not to. I am also worried that by deleting the new gmail address that my 70 odd blog posts will disappear now that they're connected to the new Gmail address.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - **don't** delete anything!

Re:  "Now I can't sign into Blogger with the first Gmail address":

I guess that when you go to the Blogger Dashboard (www.Blogger.com), you are logged in with your new address.

But can you choose sign-out (from under the icon near the top right corner)?

And then can you choose "sign in with another account", and enter your origianl Blogger/Google account name and password?

This should get you in to Blogger, using your old Google account.    If not, then you need to tell us more about what is happening.